# underscore.js access underscore-extensions.js file with newer underscore version

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I use underscore.js and backbone.js.
I try to upgrade these.

Together with underscore.js I have created a underscore-extensions.js file that I have created some of my own methods in. I use this together with underscore.js and call it the same way:

```
 _.ownMethod()
```

I had underscore version 1.4.4
I tried with some different versions, and above underscore version 1.5, the methods inside my underscore-extensions.js file can not be accessed. 
Does anybody know why?
If I want to use the latest version of Backbone, I need to install a newer version of underscore, but it seem I can not install anything newer than 1.5.

Comment: How do you add your extensions to Underscore? Should work fine if you use [`_.mixin`](http://underscorejs.org/#mixin) but you're not providing enough information.

Comment: By the way you might want to consider lodash 4~ rather than extending underscore by yourself.